# How to achieve redundancy between 2 tables of different databases?

Tags: mysql

First of all I'd like to start saying that I've checked these two questions:

[Sync 2 tables of different databases - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112257/sync-2-tables-of-different-databases-mysql)

[How to synchronize two tables of different databases on the same machine (MySql)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15941231/how-to-synchronize-two-tables-of-different-databases-on-the-same-machine-mysql)

But while similar they are not what i need.

I have 2 databases in the same server.

Db1 and Db2

Both databases have the exact copy of a single table called "user":

```
userid 
login 
name 
lastname 
password 
level
```

How can I achieve some sort of redundancy between these two tables in different databases?

If db1.user gets a new record then db2.user has to have that record, if a record is modified then the other one is modified and if deleted the then the other one gets deleted too.

To be more specific, db2.user needs to be a reflection of db1.user using triggers.

EDIT: there is this question: [Mysql replication on single server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375320/mysql-replication-on-single-server) and that is not even remotely close to what i want to do. I updated a little bit at the very end of what i previously posted with how I'd like to achieve this thanks to a suggestion.

Comment: In other words you want to *reduce* redundancy. You can accomplish this with triggers.

Comment: @Strawberry Your choice of duplicate is completely incorrect. There are two appropriate ones already provided in the question.

Comment: @strawberry that's not what i'm looking for.

Comment: @EJP Would you mind explaining how can i do it through the triggers, please? that sounds more like what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As proposed you can use triggers as stated in [this standard documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html).
You define AFTER INSERT,AFTER UPDATE and AFTER DELETE triggers on db1.user and within this trigger you have the NEW.object to pass the information into the db2.user table.